# Using AvroSchemaRegistry in Apache NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi

I have 5 different `CSVReader` controller services. Their configuration is the same except `schema text` (because different headers) and 1 `CSVRecordSetWriter`.

I want to leave only one `CSVReader` and set `schema text` dynamically. I read about `AvroSchemaRegistry` but I didn't clearly understand how to use it.

Should i create 5 different `AvroSchemaRegistry` controllers with 2 attributes: `name` and `value`?
F.e. i want to put following schema:

```
{
    "type": "record",
    "name": "campaigns",
    "namespace": "common",
    "fields": [
        {"name": "campaign_name", "type": "string"},
        {"name": "campaign_id", "type": "long"},
        {"name": "date", "type" : {"type": "int", "logicalType" : "date"}}
    ]
}
```

I should create `AvroSchemaRegistry` with:

- `name` = campaigns;
- `value` = *Full Code above*.

For another schema i should create another `AvroSchemaResgitry` controller with another attributes `name` and `value`?

After that, how to configure `CSVReader` and `CSVRecordSetWriter` to work with these schemas? And finally, what should i do with flowfiles? Add additional attributes? What kind of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure your flow something like this (make changes as per your requirement) ,

[image: flow]

1. `UpdateAttribute` configuration to derive/hard code flowfile specific schema-

[image: UpdateAttribute]

2. `ValidateRecord` configuration to use generic csv reader and pass schema dynamically -

[image: ValidateRecord]

3. `CSVReader` controller service to use dynamically passed schema and set schema access strategy -

[image: CSVReader]

If you wish to use NiFi supported schema registry then put all of your schemas in registry and set `schema.name` and `access strategy` properties for record reader/writer to access schema from registry, but first you need to add/configure schema registry provider in controller service.

**Update:**

Sample SchemaRegistry controller service configuration for `HortonworksSchemaRegistry` (ConfluentSchemaRegistry and AvroSchemaRegistry have more or less the same properties). The important thing is what parameter registry API expect when lookup operation being performed, so that we just need to pass the same value from Reader/Writer controller service `Schema Name` property, please [refer to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70310307/using-apache-nifis-confluentschemaregistry-with-apicurio-schema-registry) to get an idea.

Schema Registry URL : http://example.com:7788/api/v1

[image: HortonworksSchemaRegistry]

Comment: I'll try it! Can you, please, also provide simple configuration for schema registry in controller service? I dont know how it should look like.

Comment: Can you provide for us an exemple of schema registry configuration please ?

Comment: @FahdZaghdoudi - updated answer.