# How to generate Avro schema for csv file in nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

Sometimes I need to convert csv files to json files using ConvertRecord. So I have to set AvroSchemaRegistry in the ConvertRecord.

Is there any processor could help me generate the Avro schema for me (csv file has so many columns) so that I can put it into the AvroSchemaRegistry.

Comment: Did you try `Schema Access Strategy= Infer Schema` option?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `InferAvroSchema` processor, this will add `inferred.avro.schema` attribute to flowfile. You can make processing bit generic as well, please refer this for how to implement - [Using AvroSchemaRegistry in Apache NiFi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66367287/using-avroschemaregistry-in-apache-nifi)

You can achieve the same by configuring `Schema Access Strategy= Infer Schema` property of your record reader.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an `InferAvroSchema` in NiFi 1.19.1 - unless it has a different name or is found by some route other than the "Add Processor" button?  With "Infer Scehma" in the reader's "Schema Access Strategy", how do I view / use / edit the resulting schema?

Comment: @SarahMesser - true, seems like it is moved and made part of the record reader now.  Have a look at these articles - https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Did-InferAvroSchema-get-removed/m-p/299544  **AND** https://jd-bots.com/2021/09/10/fixed-inferavroschema-not-found-in-latest-version-of-nifi-1-10-0-and-above/