# Using Apache NiFi's ConfluentSchemaRegistry with Apicurio Schema Registry

Tags: apache-nifi, confluent-schema-registry

I want to use Apache NiFi for writing some data encoded in Avro to Apache Kafka.

Therefore i use the `ConvertRecord` processor for converting from JSON to Avro. For Avro the `AvroRecordSetWriter` with `ConfluentSchemaRegistry` is used. The schema url is set to `http:<hostname>:<port>/apis/ccompat/v6` (hostname/port are not important for this question). For having a free alternative to `Confluent Schema Registry` i deployed a `Apicurio Schema Registry`. The `ccompat` API should be compatible to Confluent.

But when i run the NiFi pipeline i get the following error, that the schema with the given name is not found:

`Could not retrieve schema with the given name [...] from the configured Schema Registry`

But i definitely created the Avro schema with this name in the Web-UI of Apicurio Registry.

Can someone please help me? Is there anybody who is using NiFi for Avro encoding in Kafka by using Apicurio Schema Registry?

**Update:**
Here are some screenshots of my pipeline and its configuration.

[image: pipeline overview]

Set schema name via `UpdateAttribute`
[image]

Use `ConvertRecord` with `JsonTreeReader`
[image]

and `ConfluentSchemaRegistry`
[image]

and `AvroSetWriter`
[image]

**Update 2:**
This artifact id has to be set:
[image]

Comment: Would it be possible to add screenshots of a few property configurations like ConvertRecord, Record Reader/Writter and Apicurio Schema Registry controller services, and also how you are passing schema name from ConvertRecord to Reader/Writter?

Comment: yes, of course. I will update the description.

Comment: Assuming `ConfluentSchemaRegistry` controller service is up and running, your config looks all good. So to troubleshoot,  can you please try using `ValidateRecord` instead of `ConvertRecord` since earlier has `Schema Name` property, try setting `twitter_raw` as value. One more thought - configure `JsonTreeReader` service  property `Schema Access Strategy` to `Use 'Schema Name' Property` (currently you have set to `Infer Schema`) and point  `Schema Registry` to Confluent Schema Registry, so that Reader/Writer both are pointing to the same schema registry and having same access strategy.

Comment: Now, it runs :) The problem was the naming of the artifact in Apicurio Schema Registry. You have to set the Aritfact-ID to `twitter_raw`. The name isnide the Avro schema doesnt matter.  But leave Group-ID blank otherwise the request of `ConfluentSchemaRegistry` will also fail. I added an screenshot of the naming field. Thanks for your help  Vikramsinh Shinde.

Comment: Hortonworks schema registry also doesn't check the Avro schema content to retrieve schema name. Glad it's sorted out!